# Iterate a dataframe depending on the value of one column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a (pandas) dataframe like this

```
f  v1 v2
0  1   2
0  2   4
0  0   4
....
0  5    1
1  2   3
1  3   4
...
1  5  7
```

Let's say this has 100 elements, and half of them are f=0 and half f=1

My goal is to make another dataframe like this

```
f  temperature
0  hot
0  hot
0  hot
....
0  hot
1  cold
1  cold
...
1  cold
```

So I am thinking that it should be a case of *iterating* through the f column?

So my question is:

Can I implement the above goal iterating through the f column? and if so, how can this iteration should be written?

Answer (score 1):

You can add a 'temperature' columns like this:

```
import numpy as np
df['temperature'] = np.where(df['f'] == 0, 'hot', 'cold')
```

alternatively, you can `map`:

```
df['tempartature'] = df['f'].map({0: 'cold', 1: 'hot'})
```

later you can pd.drop the unwanted columns

Comment: Excellent, I'll try it! One more thing. What if there are more than 0 and 1 but 0 to 10 and I want to assign labels to each for example hot from 0 to 4 and cold to 5 to 10?

Comment: Then the map method is preferable, you can add to the dictionary in it as many values as you would like

Comment: Ohh! you mean replace `{0: 'cold', 1: 'hot'}` with a dictionary that I previously create?

Comment: or  could you change the comparison statement in np.where to be `df['f'] <= 4`?

Comment: @KansaiRobot - yes. e.g.: {0: 'cold', 1: 'hot', 2:'very hot', 3:'boiling hot'}

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) with a dictionary of the 2 values and what they should translate to:

```
df['temperature'] = df['f'].replace({0:'hot', 1:'cold'})
```

Full dataframe:

```
   f  v1  v2 temperature
0  0   1   2          hot
1  0   2   4          hot
2  0   0   4          hot
3  0   5   1          hot
4  1   2   3         cold
5  1   3   4         cold
6  1   5   7         cold
```

If you then only want those 2 columns, you can do:

```
df = df[['f', 'temperature']]
```

Output:

```
   f temperature
0  0         hot
1  0         hot
2  0         hot
3  0         hot
4  1        cold
5  1        cold
6  1        cold
```

Comment: or `map` that is designed for this purpose ;)

Comment: @mozway then I would've been copying the other answer, and if it works it works :p

Comment: The drawback of replace is that it would leave an invalid value, where `map` would put a NA .